# Accessing the list in R generated as result of statistical test

Tags: r, list

The results of wald test are captured in c object using:

```
c<-wald.test(b=coef(object=OLS_op),Sigma=vcov(object=OLS_op), L=l)
c #shows results
Wald test:
----------
Chi-squared test:
X2 = 30.5, df = 1, P(> X2) = 3.3e-08
```

str(c) shows that c is List of 8. The elements are $Sigma, $b, $Terms, $H0, $L, $result, $verbose, $df. The line correspond to $ result shows that

```
$ result :List of 1 ..$ chi2: Named num [1:3] 3.05e+01 1.00 3.30e-08
```

Can some one please help in accessing the individual elements of $ result i.e. X2, df and P as they are required for further analysis.
I tried c[6][1] but it gives

```
$result
$result$chi2
        chi2           df            P 
3.052068e+01 1.000000e+00 3.303266e-08
```

I also tried c$result[[1]] but it gives

```
chi2           df            P 
3.052068e+01 1.000000e+00 3.303266e-08
```

As seen from different scenarios, I am unable to access individual element. Please help in accessing df, P, and chi2 elements individually.

Comment: Try c$result[[1]][1] and c$result[[1]][3] to access values further down a chain in a list.

Could you provide the data so that other users can attempt to replicate your results?

Comment: @Honey Dipped Badger Thanks dear...This works for me :)

Comment: Not a problem, glad to be of service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually easier to read a code if the values are accessed by their names instead of some index numbers.

In your case you could try

```
chi2 <- c$result$chi2["chi2"]
df <- c$result$chi2["df"] 
P <- c$result$chi2["P"]
```